# Clef between a beam? proper notation?

Tags: notation, clefs, beaming

[image]

Is that F Clef between the beam of those two notes in the 3rd bar proper notation? if so, what does it mean? I'm guessing it's the same as the G Clef that precedes it, so that the next note would be C instead of an A, am I right?

[This question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/33356/104) is not really the same, as my question as a whole was: is there a difference with that clef under the beam and the other clef changes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple answer: yes and yes. The first note immediately after the G clef is G below middle C; the first note after the F clef is, as you say, C an octave below middle C.