# How to play a 3 line/staff music sheet

Tags: sheet-music

I have a 3 line music piece I would like to play (I have only played the normal 2 lines). I have someone to sing the top line.

I understand for piano just play the 2 bottom lines (see below)

My question is- what notes do I actually use?

NOTE 1:
Since the second chord is F (above the top staff) and note 1 shows  A and F on the second line and  F on the third line. What is the best approach?

NOTE 2:
Same for note 2 a  C (above the top staff) and a C G on line 2 and C on line 3.

Do I play exactly as shown with mostly 2 notes from the second stave and 1 note from the bottom? Or do I play the 2 notes from the second stave and the chord from above the top staff as well?

I have seen a youtube video where it seems they play the chords (above the top stave) with the left hand and play the second stave with the right.

[image]

Comment: You just play the notes that are written. Sorry, but I don't understand your questions like "DO I play the third line as the chord and just play the two keys extra on line 2."

Comment: @user6804473, this is a re-posting of your earlier question [Music with 3 Staves](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/60926/music-with-3-staves). Please edit your original question so that others can understand what you're asking.

Comment: my prior question deviate on a discussion of Gsus, which missed my point. I have reworded a new question with more details.

Comment: @user6804473, re-posting the same question is not the right way to remedy this. Additionally, I'm not sure you've characterized your first post fairly given that all of the answers that other users posted to your first post did attempt to address the question. There's a good question here, but it's difficult to decipher the way it's worded right now, which is why you haven't gotten the answer you wanted. I encourage you to edit the first version so that the question is clearer and delete this version.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but I think you're asking whether or not to play the chords written in above.  Short answer: no.  Just play the bottom two staves, the piano part.  The chords above are mostly for guitar.  Although if you want to, you can add some of the chord tones to the piano part.

Comment: The question asker now says this: "I have seen a youtube video where it seems they play the chords (above the top stave) with the left hand and play the second stave with the right." Clearly, someone isn't following your recommendation, and the question asker is now confused.

Comment: @user6804473 If you have a further question, you should comment instead of editing my answer.