# Three Treble Clefs

Tags: piano, sheet-music, sight-reading, clefs

What does it mean when there is a layout like this, and each has a treble clef.  There is no bass clef. How is this played?[image]

Comment: Note the symbol that connects two lower staves at the far left: it means the staves are meant for a single instrument. If you take a look at the range of each stave, you'll reailze it's perfectly playable. Also note the ommision of bar lines between the upper stave and the the lower group of staves. The "layout" you're referring to is in fact a "score" (partitura)

Answer (score 5):

This is a score for voice + piano.

The uppermost line are the notes for the voice.

The grand stave below is what the piano plays.

In this case the melody is doubled in the piano (an octave higher). So the piano part will sound fine without the voice. But in some cases the piano only plays the harmony and additional melodic elements, and you need the voice to make it a finished 'product'.

See this question as well:[Piano music with two treble clefs, and notes between staves](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11463/piano-music-with-two-treble-clefs-and-notes-between-staves?rq=1)

Also in this case the grand stave consists of two staves in treble clef instead of the usual treble + bass clef. It does this because the left hand part is relatively high and it is easier to read this way.

See this question as well:
[Piano: grand staff with two treble clefs. Where to place hands?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41352/piano-grand-staff-with-two-treble-clefs-where-to-place-hands)

Answer (score 1):

Bottom two staves, piano. It follows the convention of putting left hand notes in the lower stave, right hand notes in the upper. The LH is higher than the usual LH range, so it's written using treble clef.  Very common.

The very top stave is voice. As is obvious from the character name and printed lyrics!